# Typescript Type 'string | Message | (string[] | Message[])[]' is not assignable to type 'string[] | Message[]'

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a problem with a multi type variable, `InputMessage` declaration is:

```
export type InputMessage = Message | string | Message[] | string[];
```

and I use it like this:

```
  private addMessage(msg: InputMessage, type: 'ERROR' | 'WARN' | 'INFO' | 'SUCCESS') {
    if (!msg) return;

    const arrayMsg: Message[] | string[] = msg instanceof Array ? msg : [msg];

    arrayMsg.forEach((item) => {
      this.message(item, type);
    })
  }
```

But I have an error at compilation:

```
ERROR in src/app/components/growl/growl.service.ts(52,11): error TS2322: Type '(string | Message)[]' is not assignable to type 'string[] | Message[]'.
      Type '(string | Message)[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
        Type 'string | Message' is not assignable to type 'string'.
          Type 'Message' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Can you help me, where I do an error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that if `msg` is not an array, the type of `msg` is inferred as `string | Message`. Putting that into an array makes that array implicitly `(string | Message)[]`.

One way to prevent this error is to have a second type check to allow the compiler to check for `string` or `Message`:

```
const arrayMsg: Message[] | string[] = msg instanceof Array ? msg : (typeof(msg) === 'string' ? [msg] : [msg]);
```

Another way to do this would be to explicitly cast the type the `[msg]`:

```
const arrayMsg2: Message[] | string[] = msg instanceof Array ? msg : [msg] as Message[] | string[];
```